# Как считать из файла строку с числами в коллекцию? Java

Tags: java

Считать построчно получилось, а вот как поправить так, чтобы считала объекты, например, через запятую.

К примеру строка: `5,10,5.2,true`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TaskOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<Object> ratings = new ArrayList<Object>();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("result.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            ratings.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();

        System.out.println(ratings);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Считываете строку и разбиваете ее split по делителю запятая `String[] parts = line.split(",")`, а дальше уже бегаете по parts

Comment: Для этого надо писать парсер.

Comment: Что значит `считала объекты?` то есть из вашего примера, вам нужно чтобы вывело 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строку Вы уже получили, а дальше можно применить что то такое, хоть это и не оптимально:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Object> ratings = new ArrayList<Object>();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("result.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        for (String s : line.split(",")) {
            ratings.add(parse(s));
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    System.out.println(ratings);
}

static Object parse(String s){
    try {
        return Integer.valueOf(s);
    } catch ( Exception ignored) {}

    try {
        return Double.valueOf(s);
    } catch ( Exception ignored) {}

    return Boolean.valueOf(s);
}
```

Если пытаться сделать без try-catch код получится посложнее.

Тут важен порядок попыток распарсить объект

`Boolean` надо парсить в самом конце т.к. для него все `false` все что не `"true"`

```
System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf("2")); // false
```

Так же и с `Double`:

```
System.out.println(Double.valueOf("2")); // 2.0
```

---

PS: Однако я не вижу смысла в такой структуре, наверное надо было бы создать объект `Record` с полями, которые описывают одну строку файла `result.txt`, и ими уже наполнить коллекцию.

Comment: Мне помогло спасибо большое. Главное что считывает а то я не мог сообразить как.

Comment: Если уж парсить, то методом ....parseXXX(). Imho, так красивее